# React PWA not getting Add to Homescreen option because of an error => No matching serviceworker detected

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Getting Error in Dev tools Application manifest => no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start url from the manifest.

I created the app through npx create-react-app & using its default serviceWorker but instead of production, i checked development --

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('serviceWorker' in navigator);
   console.log(window.location.href);
    return true;
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {

      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/serviceWorker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {

        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);


        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log("true"

          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(

              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {

              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');


              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {

  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' }
  })
    .then(response => {

      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Also my manifest.json file ==>

```
{
  "short_name": "PWA",
  "name": "Process Retina",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "Favicon1.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "Favicon.png",
      "sizes": "360x350",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo_top.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "87x83"
    }

  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "dir": "ltr",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary"
}
```

What am i doing wrong here to get this error/warning?
Please help me to find it out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `register` function has unreachable code. I have highlighted the piece of unreachable code in the snippet below.

```js
  export function register(config) {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      console.log('serviceWorker' in navigator);
     console.log(window.location.href);
      return true;
      // THE BELOW CODE IS UNREACHABLE.
      // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
      const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
      if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {

        return;
      }

      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/serviceWorker.js`;

        if (isLocalhost) {

          checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);


          navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
            console.log("true"

            );
          });
        } else {
          // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
          registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
        }
      });
      // TILL HERE CODE IS UNREACHABLE
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I only posted a part snippet of my serviceWorker, not the whole code. But its there in the actual code. I will post it lator. But in this code, is there any error or bug you see. Because after console my code is not working.

Comment: With [chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#application), you can check if your service worker is actually installed. Also, check the [scope of service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker#registration_and_scope), it should be root of your app so that it can control your whole app. Seeing only partial file I cannot say if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I updated my ans to include my full serviceWorker. Now please tell me the mistakes i am making. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited the answer to point out  what you are missing. @Anuja

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually deleted all this code & again recoded my service- worker which only includes events & conditions i required. It is working fine now.